# Is is possible to load more testdata with liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I want to load a whole html file as testdata with liquibase. So far I've used the approach with loading testdata from csv file, but it is not designed to handle huge html's. 
Is there a way to achieve it?

Here is an example to make it clear:

I have a table named Movie. The fields are: `id`, `title`, `description`. In a `databaseChangeLog` section I point to a file where I store the testdata:

```
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
    file="config/liquibase/testdata/movie.csv"
    separator=";"
    tableName="movie"/>
```

The content is as follows:

```
id;title;description
1;Titanic;great movie
2;Forrest Gump;another great movie
```

Now I want to change the `description` to something that is closer to the real usecase. Lets say this HTML:

```
<div id="lipsum">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porta pulvinar lacus eget egestas. Ut quis efficitur turpis. Nunc tincidunt turpis lorem, eget vestibulum nisi sodales at. Quisque in tortor et sapien ornare venenatis. Integer pulvinar nec ipsum malesuada porta. Sed massa metus, condimentum non varius ornare, sollicitudin at dui. Praesent porta, ante et interdum convallis, tellus augue tempus nisl, sit amet mollis augue nisl vel metus.
    </p>
    <p>
        Nam quis libero rhoncus, facilisis magna ut, bibendum urna. Nullam sit amet volutpat turpis. Praesent eget aliquet orci. Duis dignissim tellus erat, eget fermentum augue dapibus sed. Quisque vitae est ipsum. Quisque sit amet libero eget nisi faucibus maximus vel a sem. Proin maximus neque arcu, sit amet eleifend dolor ornare at. Suspendisse laoreet lobortis tellus sed consequat. Nunc commodo ligula eget neque porta consectetur. Mauris sagittis elit in sodales luctus.
    </p>
</div>
```

The content won't fit into the csv file. I could delete all the newlines, but it makes the file unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[loadData](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) has a [column](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) attribute which in turn has a `valueClobFile` attribute where you could put in a path to a (html) file.

Checkout these two files in the liquibase integration tests that show a use of this:

- [batchInsert.changelog.xml](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-integration-tests/src/test/resources/changelogs/common/batchInsert.changelog.xml)
- [batchInsert.csv](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-integration-tests/src/test/resources/changelogs/common/batchInsert.csv)